# Select certain fields/children of flat xml with xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, django-models

I have a xml file like a single database table, is there a way I can get "listpos"-rows of certain fields, ie. only "type" and "objName" ?

```
<listpos lfdNr="0001" reihe="20140626143443">
  <type>Akt</type>
  <objName>2@25.6.2014@40801@de</objName>
  <laborOrt>au</laborOrt>
  ...
</listpos>
<listpos lfdNr="0002" reihe="20140626181936">
  <type>Akt</type>
  <objName>2@25.6.2014@40802@de</objName>
  <laborOrt>au</laborOrt>
  ...
</listpos>
...
```

So the output should be

```
<listpos>
  <type>Akt</type>
  <objName>2@25.6.2014@40801@de</objName>
</listpos>
<listpos>
  <type>Akt</type>
  <objName>2@25.6.2014@40802@de</objName>
</listpos>
...
```

Writing this it comes to my mind it might be a job for xslt?

The whole thing I do, is trying to make django-xml work together with django_tables2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using XPath you can get that data pretty easily.

You navigate to the appropriate elements using Expressions.

For the data you're trying to extract (assuming you wanted to access all "type" and "objName" Elements), those would be `"//listpos/type"` and `"//listpos/objName"`

Those would get you the right nodes from which you can extract the content.

Comment: sorry i was not exact enough, I will edit my question

Comment: So I need a single expression where I can list all fields I want.